# PHP string with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, format

I forgot what was there command to format string (take care of ', \, /, etc) before you process it in mysql, like trim....

Comment: [Oh my...](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php)

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: There is no way this is a `mysql_real_question()`.

Answer (score 1):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)?